# use update statement but only one parameter out of the 3

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I have an normal update statement that uses 3 parameters.

What I want to do is if successful update all 3 columns but if it fails then I want to keep two columns same as what it was and then update only one column.

The table has 3 columns:

```
name    | url           | downloaded
001.jpg | D:/images.... | 1
```

If passed update all columns to new values eg:

```
1.jpg   | C:/images.... | 1
```

if failed

```
001.jpg | D:/images.... | 0
```

*downloaded is just to see if it was downloaded and saved in correct folder?

MY CODE:

```
Sub loopthroughfiles(ByVal sKey As String, ByVal clientIDs As String)
        Dim AWSAccessKey As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("AWSAccessKeyId")
        Dim AWSSecretKey As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("SecretAccessKey")
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionStringdev"))
        Dim objConfig As New AmazonS3Config()
        Try
            Dim utility As New TransferUtility(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1)

            Dim S3_KEY As String = sKey
            Dim txtFolderPath As String = "C:\\images\\"
            Dim bucket As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("bucket")

            Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath)

            For Each images As String In files
                Dim id As String = ""
                Dim photoID As String = ""
                For Each str As String In IDS
                    If Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey).Contains(str) Then
                        id = str
                    End If
                    For Each value As String In PhotoIDS
                        photoID = value
                    Next
                Next

                utility.Upload(txtFolderPath & sKey, bucket)
                Dim cannedACL As S3CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead


                Dim fileNameOnly As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey)
                Dim token As String = fileNameOnly.Remove(fileNameOnly.LastIndexOf("_"c))
                Dim number As New String(token.SkipWhile(AddressOf [Char].IsLetter).ToArray())

                Dim cmdSet As New SqlCommand("ETSP_UPDATE_PHOTO_URLS")
                cmdSet.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stype", "L")
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surl", Convert.ToString("url" & sKey))
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", 2)
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk_photo_id", photoID)
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bactive", 1)
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property_id", id)
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", clientIDs)
                Log(clientIDs)


                conn.Open()
                cmdSet.Connection = conn
                cmdSet.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log(ex.Message)
'ONLY UPDATE ONE COLUMN? "idownloaded" make it 1
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Also, have you decided which language you are using?

Comment: @crashmstr I am using vb but C# help is fine. I have code but normal update code and it works, I just want to find out if it is possible? because I have a TRY/CATCH in try update in catch only update one column if it did not download?

Comment: use an SQL [transaction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx).  On rollback you can attempt to update the one column.  (Of course, that may fail as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the `catch` you could run a statement like this:

```
var sql = "UPDATE tbl SET [downloaded] = 0 WHERE name = @name";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", originalFileName);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```